# Page not refreshing after making an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a webgrid am using and the grid has rows. I want to be able to delete
any row I want. I have a garbage icon on every row for deletion. If I click on 
it, the javascript function DeleteTaskFromDb is called below

```
     function DeleteTaskFromDb(processCompleteData) {
            var url = "@Url.Action("RemoveTaskFromList", "Home")";
            $.get(url, { 'objdata': processCompleteData }, function (data) {           
                //jQuery.removeData(data);
                //$('#mainListContent').html(data);
            });    
        }
```

In this method, I want to be able to redirect to EmployeeHoursDetail in same controller.
This is working. I hardcoded the uniqueId just for testing.

```
         public ActionResult RemoveTaskFromList(string objdata)
            {
                Employeehourstaskinfo getAllTaskSaved = null;
                try
                {
                    var stripOffObjectName = JObject.Parse(objdata)["EmployeeTask"];
                    var cleanedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employeetaskdto>(stripOffObjectName.ToString());
                    getAllTaskSaved = _dtcDataService.RemoveTaskRecordFromDb(cleanedData);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.Error(ex);
                }
                return RedirectToAction("EmployeeHoursDetail", "Home", new { uniqueId = 51207 });
            }
```

This method returns the correct data i need i.e after deleting a record from above.

```
        public ActionResult EmployeeHoursDetail(Int64 uniqueId = 0)
        {
            ...//code here
            ...
            getEmhourdetails = _dtcDataService.GetEmployeeHoursDetails(uniqueId);

            return View(getEmhourdetails);
        }
```

Problem : If I have 4 records on the webgrid and I delete 1, by the time my page reloads I can still see
the 4 records. It should only show 3 since i deleted one. I think my html page is not refreshing.
I suspect its my $.get call that is not refreshing the page.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: First, an AJAX request will not follow the redirect result -- you'll have to do that yourself with javascript on the callback. Second, a GET request may be cached by the browser so it may never make subsequent calls to your server if the URL had been used before. A POST would be better for an edit action.

Comment: Either return a new partial view to replace your content or return a new response e.g. `{ status: "OK", deleteId: "id" }` then parse this in your callback to find the element to remove. To simplify things -- since you probably know which item triggered the request you just need to check for the "OK" then remove it from the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I decided to go for the callback option and it works for me.